# Why SELECT COUNT(*) is much slower than SELECT with a WHERE clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

There's the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `refdata` (
    `id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `uid` INT NOT NULL,
    `data` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `ref_akid` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `ref_version` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `remote_addr` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `fetched_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `link_to_user` (`uid`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `link_to_user` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `selfdb`.`admin_users` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

The id is an UUID and the data is take about 1Mb.
So the table is about 1.3G with 1.3M rows.
Here's the result.

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refdata;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  1381991 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1 min 9.49 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refdata WHERE uid > 0;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  1382097 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.29 sec)
```

Why the previous query is much slower than the second query?

P.S. There an app running and insert data. Are there some reasons about the table lock?

---

Here are explains.

```
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refdata;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | refdata    | NULL       | index | NULL          | link_to_user | 4       | NULL | 1387770 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refdata WHERE uid > 0;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | refdata    | NULL       | range | link_to_user  | link_to_user  | 4       | NULL | 693885 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM refdata;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | refdata    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1387771 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM refdata WHERE uid > 0;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | refdata    | NULL       | ALL  | link_to_user  | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1387774 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: the fact that count(*) with where > count (*) with no where confuse me too

Comment: How `SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM refdata;`  performs?

Comment: @GeorgePant the same as COUNT(*). Actually I tried a lot, the cost of time won't reduce unless adding a WHERE clause.

Comment: If you don't care about transaction, using mysql issam engine will get you fast count. innodb are sequential scan tuples which makes it slow. using where is because it's doing index scan so much faster. Another way is don't using count, just issue select on some internal table_meta inside the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behavior for InnoDB tables.

InnoDB engine supports transactions.So when you perform COUNT(*), the table must be fully scanned to avoid counting rows that are not yet commited.

But when you specify a filtering condition with `WHERE` only the filtered rows need to be counted and since `UID` in your case is an indexed column that is much faster.

Comment: But the `SELECT COUNT(*)` query is slower than `SELECT *` query (It cost about 30 seconds). Is that an expected behavior?

Comment: I would guess that SELECT * uses an index...Can you edit your question and show EXPLAIN info for both queries? Also `show engine innodb status` while both queries are running would be useful.

Comment: thx, I've update my question with explains. But I can't capture `show engine innodb status` result when I run `SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE ...` query (It's too fast.)

Comment: All the EXPLAINS I can see show they each took, 
    1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Comment: Can you give ` show engine innodb status` for the slow queries you mention there is a huge difference in time? COUNT(*) and SELECT * both  without WHERΕ clause.

Comment: Sorry, I've checked again. `SELECT *` only take about 0.05 secs. (The previous result is because of remote accessing.)

Comment: But I found that if I export the data and import them to a new database. The `SELECT COUNT(*)` is much faster (about 3 secs). And after I run `OPTIMIZE TABLE `refdata``, the cost of time reduce to less than 30 secs.

Comment: @emmmsir Is the table an InnoDB in the new database and a large number of INSERTS operations is performed on it? Because that is what should make the COUNT(*) slow. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` reorganizes the physical storage of table data and associated index data, to reduce storage space and improve I/O efficiency when accessing the table.So it can definitely help in many situations.

Comment: @GeorgePant yeah, I export the database using SQL file and import to new database by SQLs. I think there're some reason about the index data. Anyway, `SELECT COUNT(*)` is slow, I think I just replace it by `SELECT ... WHERE ...`